# Formula for computing total amount per day

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have this Excel spreadsheet where in one of the columns I need to come up with a formula that will compute the total amount for a given day. This is a small snapshot of a huge spreadsheet:

```
Date/Time   Time    Amount      Balance       Total $ per day
9/30/2014   5:30 PM $5.20       $87.81  
9/30/2014   4:23 PM $0.14       $93.01  
9/30/2014   8:53 AM ($4.61)    $93.15   
9/30/2014   7:53 AM $5.20       $88.54  
9/29/2014   5:08 PM $1.09       $93.74  
9/29/2014   7:18 AM $1.09       $94.83  
9/26/2014   5:31 PM ($4.61)     $95.92
```

For this example the `Total $ per day` would be:

```
E2 $5.93 
E6 $2.18 
E8 ($4.61)
```

I'm guessing there is a formula that is much better than manually computing this by `=SUM(X#:X#)`?

Comment: Look into `SumIf()`...

Comment: Look into pivot tables.  They are a little daunting at first, but once you get the hang of them they are _really_ handy for exactly this type of task.  The learning curve actually isn't that bad.  Select all your data, Insert -> Pivot Table.  Accept defaults, and follow the instructions @pnuts gives below.  Instant results, easily adaptable to variations (sum per month, sum per hour, average, transaction counts, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $87.81 is in D2 please try, in E2 copied down to suit:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C)
```

This assumes your dollar values are numeric formatted as currency.

The formulae will return a value for each row, even where there are several rows for the same date and a PivotTable may be preferable. `Date/Time` for ROWS, and Sum of Amount for Σ VALUES. This assumes Date/Time and Time are distinct columns.

For a PT the data need not be sorted in order.

Answer (score 13):

In E2, put in the following formula:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,SUMIF(A:A,A2,C:C),"")
```

Then drag it down.

Basically, you're saying:

- IF: There's a new date in column A (not the same as the date above it),
- THEN: Sum all the values from column C that have the same value in column A
- ELSE: Return an empty cell

That should do the trick.

Comment: Really thanks. This saved me. Is that any possibility to show the date of this "best/worst records" aswell ? Thanks

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Works like a charm.